# Joining a dataframe based on multiple conditions using dplyr

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have two dataframes

**DF1**

```
Name   Industry     Division     Job
Billy  Cameras      Finance      Analyst
Jane   Cameras      Finance      Scientist
Marge  Lightening   Operations   Analyst
```

**DF2**

```
Industry     Division        Job_        Rate
Cameras      Finance         Analyst     45
Cameras      Finance         Scientist   24
Cameras      Operations      Analyst     23
Cameras      Operations      Scientist   41
Lightening   Operations      Analyst     10
Lightening   Finance         Analyst     101
```

So I want to left join DF2 to DF1, and it's simple bc it's just based on if Industry, Division, and Job are common. But how do i do this AS WELL AS having different var names.

```
DF1 %>% 
  left_join(DF2, by = c('Industry', 'Division', 'Job`))
```

So I need to have Job go to Job_. I cannot rename.

End result:

```
Name   Industry     Division     Job         Rate
Billy  Cameras      Finance      Analyst     45
Jane   Cameras      Finance      Scientist   24
Marge  Lightening   Operations   Analyst     10
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `=` to specify the names of each dataset if there is any difference

```
library(dplyr) 
DF1 %>% 
      left_join(DF2, by = c('Industry', 'Division', 'Job' = 'Job_'))
#   Name   Industry   Division       Job Rate
#1 Billy    Cameras    Finance   Analyst   45
#2  Jane    Cameras    Finance Scientist   24
#3 Marge Lightening Operations   Analyst   10
```

---

With `base R` `merge`, there is `by.x` and `by.y` to specify names that are different in the datasets